# Inserting an Event with Google Calendar API with a Hangout Conference attached

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I want to insert an event using the Google Calendar API with a Hangout Conference.

I've tried using the conferenceData key with no results.

What is the right way to do this?

I've done it like this:

```php
function getClient()
{
...... ......
...... ......
    return $client;
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$conferenceDataArr = array(
    'conferenceId' => 'aaa-bbb-ccc',
    'conferenceSolution' => array(
        'key' => array(
            'type' => 'hangoutsMeet'
        ),
        'name' => 'Reunión en VideoConferencia',

    ),
    'entryPoints' => array(
        'accessCode' => '55555',
        'entryPointType' => 'video',
        'label' => 'meet.google.com/aaa-bbbb-ccc',
        'uri' => 'https://meet.google.com/aaa-bbbb-ccc'
    )
);

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
    'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
    'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
    'start' => array(
      'dateTime' => '2019-07-26T11:54:00',
      'timeZone' => 'Europe/Madrid',
    ),
    'end' => array(
      'dateTime' => '2019-07-26T20:00:00',
      'timeZone' => 'Europe/Madrid',
    ),
    'attendees' => array(
      array('email' => 'me@gmail.com'),
    ),
    'reminders' => array(
      'useDefault' => FALSE,
      'overrides' => array(
        array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 0)
      ),
    ),
    'conferenceData' => $conferenceDataArr
  ));

  $calendarId = 'primary';

  $optParams = Array(
    'sendNotifications' => true,
    'sendUpdates' => 'all',
    );

  $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event, $optParams);
  printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
  printf('Hangout link: %s\n', $event->hangoutLink);
```

Answer (score 5):

I also found myself in endless searching and trying. I almost hacked my use case with the immediately working NodeJS API.

This is how i got it working: First you need to execute the insert method and afterwards you can add the conference with the patch method.

Here is my working example:

```php
$event = new \Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
    'summary' => 'Appointment',
    'location' => 'Earth',
    'description' => 'Hello world',
    'start' => array(
        'dateTime' => Carbon::now()->format('c'),
        'timeZone' => 'Europe/Zurich',
    ),
    'end' => array(
        'dateTime' => Carbon::now()->addMinutes(15)->format('c'),
        'timeZone' => 'Europe/Zurich',
    )
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);

printf('Event created: %s', $event->htmlLink);

$conference = new \Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceData();
$conferenceRequest = new \Google_Service_Calendar_CreateConferenceRequest();
$conferenceRequest->setRequestId('randomString123');
$conference->setCreateRequest($conferenceRequest);
$event->setConferenceData($conference);

// ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1] is required!
$event = $service->events->patch($calendarId, $event->id, $event, ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1]);

printf('<br>Conference created: %s', $event->hangoutLink);
```

Hopefully it works for you as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually I was adding the conferenceDataVersion to event data and it wasn't working. After adding ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1] to insert method it worked at first (without need to patch). 

$service->events->insert($calendarId, $event, ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1]);

Answer (score 1):

I'm using JavaScript but [the APIs are the same](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#conferenceData). I had to set the `conferenceDataVersion` in my `insert()` and I used a `createRequest` in `conferenceData` as follows:

```js
conferenceData: {
  createRequest: {
    requestId: '123456790',
    conferenceSolutionKey: {
      type: 'hangoutsMeet',
    },
    status: {
      statusCode: 'success'
    }
  },
}
```